# If I want to change the binaries of a Windows Service, do I need to reinstall it, or can I just restart it?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-services

I will occasionally need to update a service on a Windows machine. I currently have admin access, but wont in the future. I've done some quick testing and found that it still manages to work if I just stop the service, replace the binaries, and start it again. But is this always the case?

For example, if I add or remove packages to the service, do I need to reinstall? Does the actual `installutil` command do any sort of registering of content? What if I need to rename some files?

Comment: Although this does not answer your question, it may give you insight and cause you to rethink your steps: Starting and stopping services require administrative rights. Even if it works, you may still not be able to do this later on.

Comment: @LPChip You can set up services that can be stopped/started without admin rights. That part I'm no worried about.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to bring it up. Wasn't aware if this was possible in your situation.

Comment: On a server, I've run into issues occasionally, in the situation you describe, where a Windows Service is in use and *can't* be stopped at that time (sometimes requiring complete shutdown of a service using it, such as IIS, or even of the server). That is not dependent on user privilege, though, and is problematic for Administrator, too.